# Задача распределения элементов по высоте?

Tags: javascript, математика

Имеются элементы и известна их высота. 
Их нужно распределить на 3 колонки и стремится к тому, чтобы высота этих колонок была одинаковой. То есть расположить n элементов в m колонках. Один элемент может находится только в одной колонке, а в одной колонке может находиться сколько угодно элементов.

Как точно называется задача и есть ли подобные реализации на javascript?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Плохой вариант. В первой колонке много элементов а во второй и третьей мало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хороший вариант. Элементы равномерно распределены по колонкам и высота подобрана правильно.

Comment: а что именно нужно оптимизировать? разницу в сумме высот? В общем, какой критерий оптимальности.

Comment: @OlmerDale, несмотря что у нас формального критерия удачности расположения еще нету, я думаю что наилучшего результата с помощью одной сортировки достичь - не удастся.

Comment: Критерий оптимальности это разница в сумме высот всех колонок, чем она меньше тем лучше. То есть колонки должны стремиться быть одинаковыми по высоте. 
Добавил картинки.

Comment: Количество колонок может быть любым? Или нужно искать именно минимальное количество колонок, при которых выполняется условие?

Comment: Нет не любых, а 3 колонки.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться, предположу, что минимизация суммарной высоты вполне подойдёт.

Comment: @manking, [masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: Вы можете использовать CSS Flexbox для создания гибких контейнеров и распределения элементов внутри них. Flexbox позволяет легко управлять высотой и распределением элементов в колонках.